# What's are the consequences of subject expansion property?

Tags: type-theory, term-rewriting

*Subject reduction* is a well and widely used property of typed rewriting systems.
*Subject expansion* is much less known.
What are the applications of this property and which systems enjoy it?

Comment: Would you care to explain or give a reference to "subject expansion"? What is it supposed to be? I suppose you mean the one mentioned by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_reduction)? The question is still too wide and unclear.

Comment: Hey Andrej, I tried to make the question specific, but perhaps I could just ask "what is subject expansion?". I've seen it defined or used [here](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~erikb/onderwijs/sl2/materiaal/tt-sl2.pdf), [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1c4a/e7848dfe6252ad9fe7b07f6b69abce507418.pdf) and [here](http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/topps/D-327.pdf). I have an intuition that it is somehow strongly related to the property of intersection type systems of characterizing normalizable terms. But that's a specutlation and I did not want to include it in the question.